# Connect signalr with vue / vuex

Tags: vue.js, signalr, vuex

I am trying to connect SignalR hub to a Vue component but I fail doing that. i googled "vue with signalr" and real almost every link up to second page.
I getting a cors origin, but I dont think that this is the main problem, since my post/get call to web api are working well.
c# port number 63213 , client at 8080

I also using vuex and i am wonder if I should connect in at the store.
here are code examples. I use vue/vuex with typescript falvor.

```
  mounted: function() {
    //... under mounted, signalR connection.  i am using import * as signalR from "@aspnet/signalr";  
  this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("http://localhost:63213/ChatHub")
      .build();

    // connecting to the hub
    this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => console.log("connection started"))
      .catch(err => console.log("connecting hub failed err is : ", err));

    //at the hub there is a function named broadcastMessage, should return string that will be added to an array. should it be at sotr's getter  
    this.connection.on("broadcastMessage", function(msg: string) {
      this.messages.push({ msg });
    });
  },
```

c#

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var policy = new CorsPolicy()
            {
                AllowAnyOrigin = true,
                AllowAnyHeader = true,
                AllowAnyMethod = true,
                SupportsCredentials = true
            };

            policy.Origins.Add("http://localhost:8080");

            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
```

- pot get to web api are working well.

hub

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
    {

        public static void SendMessage(string msg)
        {
            var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
            hubContext.Clients.All.broadcastMessage(msg, " !! !! ");
        }
    }
```

error is:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:63213/ChatHub/negotiate' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

should i pass the hub connention to the store?
what am i doing wrong?

thank you.

Comment: Issue solved, I will upload a full solution with TS falvor. Using .netCore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

switched to .core object.

under "Configure"

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());

app.UseSignalR(route => {route.MapHub<UserHub>("/user-hub");} );
```

under 
ConfigureServices

```
services.AddSignalR();
services.AddCors();
```

at vue component (ts)

```
created: function() {
    this.$userHub.$on("user-added-event", this.userAddedEvent);
  },
  beforeDestroy: function() {
    //clean SignalR event
    this.$userHub.$off("user-added-event", this.userAddedEvent);
  },
```

user-hub.js used to handle connection.
imported as vue plugin

```
import { HubConnectionBuilder, LogLevel } from "@aspnet/signalr";
export default {
  install(Vue) {

    const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(`${Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.baseURL}/user-hub`) 
      .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
      .build();


    const userHub = new Vue();

    Vue.prototype.$userHub = userHub;

    connection.on("AddUserEvent", (userId, userName) => {
      userHub.$emit("user-added-event", { userId, userName });
    });

    // if connection closed, reopen it
    let startedPromise = null;
    function start() {
      startedPromise = connection.start().catch(err => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
          setTimeout(
            () =>
              start()
                .then(resolve)
                .catch(reject),
            5000
          )
        );
      });
      return startedPromise;
    }

    connection.onclose(() => start());

    start();
  }
};
```

full project will be uploaded to git.